# Is my leakcanary working? How to know?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I believe to have successfully installed LeakCanary.

I added the debug, release, and test dependencies to the build.gradle file.

I added the necessary files to my Application Class.  Imported as necessary.  Confirmed the application class is properly added to manifest.  Does my application class need to be explicitly called?

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

I run my app on the emulator and don't see anything different.  I monitor the Android Monitor and don't see any difference.  How do I know if it's all working? I've shared my Application class.

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import com.squareup.leakcanary.LeakCanary;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
        return;
    }
    LeakCanary.install(this);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
}
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does my application class need to be explicitly called?

No.

> How do I know if it's all working?

Leak something intentionally. For example, assign your launcher activity instance to a `static` field.

Comment: I tried, but maybe I did it wrong.  I googled common memory leaks and tried those two.  No change.  I must have done something wrong.  What should I expect to see from leak canary if it's working correctly?

Comment: @seeking_stillness: "I googled common memory leaks and tried those two" -- LeakCanary does not detect arbitrary memory leaks out of the box. The only thing it will detect automatically is a leaked activity. This is why I suggested that you leak an activity by assigning one to a `static` field. "What should I expect to see from leak canary if it's working correctly?" -- after an activity is destroyed (e.g., you press BACK), after a few seconds, if LeakCanary believes that the activity you destroyed was leaked, you will see a custom `Toast` appear, indicating that LeakCanary is dumping the heap.

Comment: @seeking_stillness: Then, a minute or so later, if there was a leak, you should see a `Notification` in the status bar.

Comment: Notification in status bar  <----   Yes I see it now!

Answer (score 3):

First, check if you are attached to a debugger? [LeakCanary ignores leak detection when debugging](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ#i-know-i-have-a-leak-why-doesnt-the-notification-show) to avoid false positives.

Second, [Add the LeakCanary via Gradle](https://github.com/square/leakcanary/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-use-it) and then do the following:

```
class App : Application() {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun getRefWatcher(context: Context): RefWatcher {
            val applicationContext = context.applicationContext as App
            return applicationContext.refWatcher
        }
    }

    private lateinit var refWatcher: RefWatcher

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
            // This process is dedicated to LeakCanary for heap analysis.
            // You should not init your app in this process.
            return;
        }
        refWatcher = LeakCanary.install(this)
    }
}
```

In your Fragment (best you use a BaseFragment)

```
override fun onDestroy() {

   if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
      activity?.let {
         App.getRefWatcher(it).watch(this)
      }
      super.onDestroy()
}
```

Then in one of your Sub-Activities with a Fragment do:

```
class MemLeakFragment : BaseFragment() {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        lateinit var memleak: Activity
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        activity?.let {
            memleak = it
        }
    }
}
```

Open the Activity with the `memleak` Fragment and close it with a back press. Wait a bit and LeakCanary will report the memory leak, this can take a while...

Comment: Where is the `toWatch` coming from ?

Comment: Sorry, I used a LifecycleObserver to handle the Lifecycle. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Paul, Should I wait for hours or even more?